# AWS Scheduling Mechanism?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to delay an email being sent for X days. This could be days, weeks, or months.

Is there anything out there other than Step Functions?

Some concerns I had with Step Functions, which could be debunked:

- The longest wait cannot exceed a year
- If the stack is deleted during long running waits. Does that in turn delete the wait task?

Comment: Not familiar with `Step Functions`, so may suggest only this way: Store tasks in some small `RDS` DB → Use `Eventbridge` to run `Lambda` periodically and check DB → If `X` time (got from DB record) is happens add email task to `SQS` (that will call another `Lambda`) or send it directly inside current function (if not many emails)

Comment: I agree with @rzlvmp. Using Step Functions isn't ideal for long-running logic. Much better to write your own logic based on entries in a database.

Comment: @rzlvmp I was thinking of that solution too. The trouble with it in my mind, is very wasteful (periodically scanning/querying DDB to get a matching time) and lack of precision (it's only as good as how frequent the checks are, and there will be bulk emails being generated at the same time). Just thought there might be a more eloquent approach that I wasn't seeing.

Comment: `is very wasteful` → yep. That is. `lack of precision` → by the way EventBridge has not perfect precision at all. Invocation may be late for 10-30 seconds. If you want high precision scheduler, it should be long running daemon (ECS task?) with socket connection or long polling. Also if you don't have many tasks you may create EventBridge job with exact time for exact task that will be run only once at necessary time and self-deleted after success execution. That will allow to remove periodical job checker. But max number of rules has hard limits per AWS account

Answer (score 1):

You can define an event rule in either Cloudwatch or EventBridge that triggers on a schedule (fixed or based on cron expression). The event target can be either SNS Topic or a Lambda function to send the email.

Please refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html) for more details

Comment: Similar to the other answer. Isn't this method quite wasteful and loses the precise time for triggering the event (scheduled for a certain time, but that depends on the cron or fixed configuration when it's actually scooped up)?

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution out. It should be what you need. It is a combination of Step Function and the DB solutions mentioned above which addresses the issues being raised (max wait time and inefficient scanning).

https://github.com/aws-samples/step-functions-workflows-collection/tree/main/smart-cron-job/